# NodeMCU build custom firmware by Docker protocol error

Tags: docker, firmware, nodemcu

My computers operating system is Windows 7. I installed Docker Toolbox and i use Docker quickstart terminal like [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/marcelstoer/nodemcu-build/). I sent

```
 git clone https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware.git
```

command and existed nodemcu-firmware file in my C:\Users\user folder. I edited user_models , user_version and user_config files. After then I sent

```
docker run --rm -it -v "//c/Users/user/<nodemcu-firmware>":/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
```

this command. This returned protocol error. The error is

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: mkdir /c/Users/user/<nodemcu-firmware>: protocol error.
```

Where did i make mistake and how can i solve this ?

Comment: `<nodemcu-firmware>` in the Docker command is meant to be a placeholder for the path or folder name of your NodeMCU firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by this code

```
docker run --rm -it -v "//c/Users/user/nodemcu-firmware":/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
```

When i tried this code returned a error to. The error about downloading "esp_iot_sdk_v1.5.1_16_01_08.zip" file and open archive. So i download "esp_iot_sdk_v1.5.1_16_01_08.zip" file manually and put the cache file in nodemcu-firmware. Finally existed integer and float .bin file with .map file. Also existed 0x00000 and 0x10000 bin file. I flashed my integer firmware file to 0x000000 adress and its working normaly.

Why did exist 0x00000 and 0x10000 bin file ?

Comment: The NodeMCU make files produce two individual `.bin` files. The command `srec_cat` in the Dockerfile concatenates them into a single `.bin` with timestamp, branch name, etc.

Comment: `esp_iot_sdk_v1.5.1_16_01_08.zip` is the ESP8266 SDK from Espressif. It is downloaded by the NodeMCU make files because we don't want to have the SDK in the NodeMCU repository.